# Divisors of numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

> Prove for any given (n,m) there are n consecutive numbers that m divides the number of their divisors.

I know that $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} ... p_n^{\alpha_n}$ have $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)... (\alpha_n+1)$ divisors but couldn't use it to prove that. I asked this at math.stackexchange.com and didn't get any help so I'm asking it here.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow. For anybody interested, the Math SE post (now deleted) referenced above is at [Number of divisors of n numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091868/602049).

Answer (score 4):

You want $n$ consecutive integers each divisible by some prime exactly $m-1$ times. So start by choosing some $n$ distinct primes, say $q_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Look for some $k$ such that, for each $i$ as above, $k+i$ is divisible by ${q_i}^{m-1}$ but not by ${q_i}^m$; then $k+1,\dots,k+n$ will serve as the desired $n$ integers.  Fortunately, the existence of such a $k$ is immediate by the Chinese remainder theorem.